# Delete items of MultiSelectList in Windows phone 7

Tags: list, windows-phone-7

how can i delete items in multiselectlist

My code's working not correctly

```
                for (int i = MyListBox.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                //for (int i = -1; i <= MyListBox.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (MyListBox.IsSelectionEnabled == true)
                    {
                        MyObservable.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
```

MyListBox : multiSelectList

MyObservable : ObservableCollection<>

Answer (score 0):

you are unable to remove the items because you are altering the collection while trying to use the collection. You need to gather the items you want to delete, then delete them as such:

```
            ICollection<Item> selectedItems = new List<Item>(MyListBox.SelectedItems.Count);
        foreach (var item in MyListBox.SelectedItems)
        {
            Item myItem = item as Item;
            if (myItem == null) continue;

            selectedItems.Add(myitem);
        }
        foreach (var item in selectedItems)
        {
            MyObservable.Remove(item);
        }
        MyListBox.IsSelectionEnabled = false;
```